# Função para ler arquivo em C

Tags: c, arquivo, formatação

Qual função usar em C para ler arquivo, linha por linha, e em cada linha contém tipos de dados diferentes?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente o que precisa é alguma variação do [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Eventualmente pode usar também [`vfscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfscanf).

Answer (score -1):

Para ler arquivo você pode utilizar o `fgets` :

```
#define N 10000
    [...]
      FILE *arquivo;
      arquivo=fopen("lugar.txt","r");
            if(arquivo == NULL)
            printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    else{
      while (fgets(linha, sizeof linha, arq3)) {
       //e se quiser escrever na tela na tela
       printf("%s",linha);
      }
     fclose(arquivo);
      }
```

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta, no fgets que você usou, no caso linha, é uma struct que você criou ?

Comment: linha é um vetor de char